# Dynamically generating components with Ember, Rails and AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, ember.js

I would like to create a blog with an Ember front-end, a Rails API acting as the back-end and and AWS to store the images. I was thinking of dividing up the posts into objects: paragraph, image, etc... and storing them in a relational database (postgres). This would then allow me to generate the corresponding Ember components on the front-end depending on the model i.e. render a paragraph component for each paragraph, an image component for each image, etc. I figured this would allow me greater flexibility when displaying the posts The end goal would be to also create the CMS to manage the blog. Is this the right way to go about this?

Comment: Sounds good. maybe also checkout cardstack.

Comment: If your backend is Rails, you should look into Fae for the CMS. It's flexible and can wrap any data model. https://www.faecms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the right way to go about this?

Your approach is good. A solution should depend on flexibility need when it comes to displaying, manipulating these paragraphs, images etc. If only CSS styling isn't sufficient then sure, you can go with storing each paragraph, image as a separate entity in the database. It should be very easy on Ember side to work with such API.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as you said : a document is a set/group of entities (images, paragraph,...)  or you can keep it simple : store the content of the blog post in a specific syntax (example: markdown) and when display you can prefix image to AWS.

For sure the more, you divide the more you are flexible, but you will need to have more relation between entities